# Check if three given vertices from undirected graph belong to a simple cycle in most efficient way

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Is it possible to perform some sort of pre-processing that would allow to answer the question efficiently (fast)?

The graph is connected, undirected, has no self loops neither parallel edges (a cycle is formed by at least three nodes).

Note that this a yes/no query, meaning that I just need to know whether such a cycle exits, which one doesn't matter.

Preprocessing should be efficient as well (ideally less than $O(m^2)$ both time and space) where $m$ is the number of edges.

Edit: The cycle is simple (no vertex in the cycle is repeated)

Edit2: My progress so far and where I'm blocking:

I'm separating the graph into sub-components through [articulation points](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/), and then doubling articulation points in each sub-component they originally separated. This came from the following observation: 3 given vertices may belong to a cycle **iff** they all belong to a component with no articulation points. I have not proved this but I couldn't think of a counter example.

Assuming the observation above is correct (which seems very likely), the problem now is the 3 given vertices in the query may all be articulation points, in which case all of them would belong to several components, which in the worst case could lead to a slow O(n) query time complexity.

Another observation that seem helpful to address the described worst case is: there's at most 1 sub-graph to which 2 given articulation points may both belong to at the same time (I can prove this if needed), the observation easily leads to a worst case pre-processing space and time of $O(n^2)$ (n is number of vertices), versus constant time queries, however $O(n^2)$ preprocessing time is too slow ($O(n^2)$ space is also too greedy). Can preprocessing be improved for a trade off of maybe log(n) query time expense?

Comment: The trivial answer would be "Pre-process by computing the answer for all $\binom{n}{3}$ triples and then solve the queries by table lookup", so I guess you're looking for some sort of trade-off between cost of preprocessing and cost of querying. (Sorry for making points one at a time -- that wasn't my intention!)

Comment: Are you interested in simple loops (A<->B<->C<->A) or the vertices may be part of bigger cycle? How large is your graph? If verices are part of several cycles, you can discard that info and only answer "yes"? Have you considered finding all cycles and building a hash table with results? Sorry if I misunderstood the objective.

Comment: if by simple loop you mean a loop involving only 2 vertices then no, see original post "a cycle is formed by at least 3 nodes", also from original post "there's no parallel edges"

Comment: If instead of 3 nodes you had 2 nodes, the answer would be to calculate biconnected components. Perhaps here you need to calculate the triconnected components.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPQR_tree

Comment: Do you require a *simple* cycle (i.e., no vertex in the cycle is repeated), or are you OK with repeated vertices?   If the latter, what's wrong with computing connected components?  Can you edit the question to clarify so people don't need to read the comments to understand the question?

Comment: Question edited, thanks for the note.

Comment: @Yuval I am not not sure if belonging to a triconnected component would guarantee a 3-vertex cycle, however it is clearly not a necessary condition i.e. 3 nodes can belong to a cycle graph component (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) for instance which is not triconnected, and yet answer the query positively.

Comment: @Evil if my understanding is correct SPQR trees are used to determine whether a component is triconnected, which is not a necessary condition for the query I described in the question (see my comment above).

Comment: My observation: it suffices to answer the following question: for three vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, ask whether there is a path between $A$ and $B$ in the graph $G \backslash C$ (i.e. a path that doesn't pass $C$). At this point it might depend on the nature of your graph. From your description, it seems that it's somewhat sparse (i.e. $m$ is much smaller than $n^2$, with $m$, $n$ the number of edges and vertices, resp.). I don't know how to proceed without more precise information.

Comment: thanks for sharing your thought, why do you think that's sufficient? here's a straightforward counter example: consider a graph with only 3 points A, B and C forming a line in that order (only 2 edges (A, B), (B, C)), here we have a path from A to B, without C, yet there's no cycle.

Comment: You misunderstood my point. You should apply my test to all three triples: $(A, B, C)$, $(B, C, A)$, $(C, A, B)$. In other words, your original question about three vertices $A, B, C$ has a positive answer if and only if: there is a path between $A, B$ avoiding $C$, AND there is a path between $B, C$ avoiding $A$, AND there is a path between $C, A$ avoiding $B$. Hence the time complexity of your question is at most three times that of my question.

Comment: This is still wrong, here's a counter example: consider a graph with only 4 vertices A, B, C and D, now if A, B and D form a simple cycle A-B-D-A and C is only connected to say D (total number of edges is 4), such a graph meets all your mentioned requirements for A, B and C yet they don't form a simple cycle.